# How to delete a list element from a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this one :

```
 [[1, 'Reason', [('reason',), ('other_reason',)]], [2, 'other', [('dep',), 
('path',)]], [3, "foo", [('bar',), ('bar1',)]] ]
```

I have this list in a function that sometimes return it as it is (an edit mode)  and in (show details)  mode change the last element from the last position to the first position , so the list will be like :

```
 [ [1, "foo", [('bar',), ('bar1',)]], [2, 'other', [('dep',), ('path',)]], 
[3, 'Reason', [('reason',), ('other_reason',)]]]
```

I want to remove the list that contains 'Reason' (the first list in the first example ).

I tried using `list.index('Reason')` method to have index but it is not working since 'Reason' is not an element of the list.

also the index is not the same so `del list[0]` is not a good choice

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
>>> l = [[1, 'Reason', [('reason',), ('other_reason',)]], [2, 'other', [('dep',), ('path',)]], [3, "foo", [('bar',), ('bar1',)]] ]>>>
>>> [e for e in l if 'Reason' not in e]
[[2, 'other', [('dep',), ('path',)]], [3, 'foo', [('bar',), ('bar1',)]]]
>>>
```

Explanation: this builds a new list from the first one, putting in it all elements *except* the ones containing `'Reason'`.

Comment: This doesn't replace the last element into the first, plus it creates a new list instead of modifying the existing list.

Comment: From the question, I only understand the reversion as already been done. I add the relevant part then.

Comment: @Vinny actually changing the order does not seem to be part of the question. As far as I understand, it was only there to tell the elements' order may change, that's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) 
yup, changing the order is not a part of the question

Answer (score 1):

```
[l for l in list if not "Reason" in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume 'Reason' changes, so keep it in a variable **removal**. The code below *manipulates the existing list*

```
l = [[1, 'Reason', [('reason',), ('other_reason',)]], [2, 'other', [('dep',), ('path',)]], [3, "foo", [('bar',), ('bar1',)]]]

removal = 'Reason'

for idx, nest_list in enumerate(l):
    if nest_list[1] == removal:
        del l[idx]

# to change element to first pos
l.insert(0, l[-1])
del l[-1]
```

Then iterate over the list, look if the item in position 1 in the sublist matches. If it does, delete it from the list.